# Yet another onNewIntent() issue | still not called

Tags: android

Using FirebaseMessagingService to generate notification. 
After tapping on it, activity is shown, but onNewIntent() is not called.
Running on 7.1.

GOAL:

- receive FCM notifications - works
- after tapping on notification, bring up activity and display notification message in a dialog box - doesn't work

  - activity shows up,
  - extras.getString() returns null.

After studying many posts so far i got this, what else am i missing ?

Thanks.

EDIT: added onResume() method, extras variable is not null, strings are null

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder =
        new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setVibrate(new long[] {0,400,150,400});

mBuilder.setNumber(++count);

Intent pushIntent = new Intent(this, PushMeMessageDialogActivity.class);
pushIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
pushIntent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_TOPIC, title);
pushIntent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_MESSAGE, message);
pushIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
pushIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

PendingIntent pushPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, count, pushIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pushPendingIntent);

NotificationManager notifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notifyMgr.notify(count, mBuilder.build());
```

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_dialog);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if(extras == null)
        return;

    String strTopic = extras.getString(Constants.INTENT_TOPIC);
    String strMessage = extras.getString(Constants.INTENT_MESSAGE);
}

<activity
    android:name=".PushMeMessageDialogActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

minSdkVersion 22
targetSdkVersion 28
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Pass title and message to activity and display it after tapping on notification.

Comment: is actvity `PushMeMessageDialogActivity` appearing or no after clicking on `notification` ?

Comment: tapping on notification makes the activity show up, can't get passed strings from extras though

Comment: take `intent global` paste this in `onCreate`      `intent=getIntent();
    String    id=intent.getStringExtra(Constants.INTENT_TOPIC);
        Log.e("TAG",id);`

Comment: onCreate() is not called after tapping on notification, only after starting the app
edit: after turning the screen off, waking up and tapping on notification, onCreate() is called, string is null

Answer (score 1):

`onNewIntent` will not be called every time the activity is shown, as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)). Only if the `Activity` already existed it will be brought to the top of the stack and `onNewIntent` will be called. If the `Activity` didn't already exist the `onCreate` will be called.

For most use cases this means that for `singleTop` `Activities` you call `setIntent` in the `onNewIntent` method and call `getIntent` in the `onResume`. That way you always process the `Intent` that brought the `Activity` to the top of the stack.

Comment: updated with onResume() method, strings are null, extras != null